# What does adjacent similar triangles mean?

Tags: geometry, triangles, quadrilateral

**PROBLEM**

In a convex quadrilateral $ABCD$, any triangle determined by a side and the point of intersection of the diagonals has the same area as the adjacent similar triangles. Show that the quadrilateral is a parallelogram.

**Drawing**

[image]

**IDEA**

Okey, so I'm really confused.

What does adjacent similar triangles? Like, the adjacent similar triangles of $\bigtriangleup  AOB$ are $\bigtriangleup BOC$ and $\bigtriangleup AOD$?

If so, I can simply solve the problem, but it seems too easy so I wanna be sure if this is the correct answer.

If so, we can simply see that the area of $\bigtriangleup AOB$ is the height multiplied by $OB$

Then we write that the area of $\bigtriangleup AOD$ is the height multiplied by $OD$, so $OD=OB$.

The same thing with $\bigtriangleup AOB, \bigtriangleup BOC => AO=OC$.

Now we could simply show the requirements.

Hope one of you can help me, telling me if the idea is correct! Thank you!

Comment: You are correct that triangles AOB and BOC are adjacent: i.e. they share a side. The problem asks you to assume the triangles are indeed similar. And use that to show it is a parallelogram.

Comment: @vallev So my idea of writing the area of both triangle and then showing that $OD=OB$ is correct?

Comment: Has this been translated from another language? As it seems that the statement already follows if the _adjacent_ triangles have the same area, without assuming similarity - I am coming to suspicion that the word "similar" is used loosely, i.e. not to mean _geometrically similar_ but to mean something like "similarly defined".

Comment: And, yes, your solution is correct (without assuming similarity!): the point $O$ halves both diagonals, therefore the quadrilateral is a parallelogram.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Yes, I translated from my native language with the help of google translate. I thought that it didn't mean geometrically similar too, but I wanted to make sure. The answer sees the problem differently. I think his idea is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are given that each of the four triangles is equal to the two triangles adjacent to it, which are also similar (to each other, not to the first triangle).

Thus for example$$\triangle AOB=\triangle AOD=\triangle BOC$$and$$\triangle AOD\sim\triangle BOC$$But equal triangles under the same height have equal bases.
Therefore$$DO=OB$$and$$AO=OC$$And a quadrilateral whose diagonals bisect each other is a parallelogram.
[image: adjacent triangles are similar]
This can further be seen as follows: since $\triangle AOD\sim\triangle BOC$, then$$\angle DAO=\angle BCO$$and hence$$AD\parallel BC$$And since triangles which are equal and similar are also congruent, then$$AD=BC$$This implies (Euclid, *Elements I, 33*) that $AB$ is equal and parallel to $DC$, and hence that $ABCD$ is a parallelogram.